# How to use "hover"(CSS) action in Styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I used Styled-components in my React.js app. I want to make some area blur on mouse hover action. So I tried to use `&:hover` and all line works fine in `&:hover` area except backdrop effect.

How to make blur effect (on mouse over) in styled-components?

> My code

```
const Adiv = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ffa5;
  &:hover {
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);          // This line doesn't work
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px);  // This line doesn't work
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
`
```

But when I try in normal HTML (such as w3schools.com/"Try it yourself"), it works well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #aaa {
          width: 300px; 
          height: 60px; 
          position: absolute; 
          top: 150px; 
          left: 50px;
      }
      #aaa:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
          backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
          border: 1px solid red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <div id="aaa">bbbbbbb</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Edited**

I want to get this effect like above image.
I don't want the text inside the div to blur. `filter` gives a blur effect to the text itself in the div. I just want to give blur effect to the letters behind div when mouse hover. So I want to use `backdrop-filter`.

Only when I use styled-components, it doesn't work. I am still curious why. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the css entities `backdrop-filter` and `-webkit.backdrop-filter` are not what you have described in your image.

Backdrop-filter applies to the elements behind the target node, while filter applies to the node itself. In order to look like the image you added, the styled component would be:

```js
const Adiv = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ffa5;
  &:hover {
    webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
`
```

The results looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I updated screen image on the post. I don't want the text inside the div to blur. `filter`  gives a blur effect to the text itself in the div. I just want to give blur effect to the letters behind div.